# Storing all elements as a list in Python

Tags: python, list

I want to print all elements as a list. I have included the current and expected outputs.

```
for i in range(0,3):
    P=i
print(P)
```

The current output is

```
0
1
2
```

The expected output is

```
[0,1,2]
```

Comment: So put them in a list...

Comment: `print(list(range(0,3)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
l = list() # create an empty list
for i in range(0,3):
    l.append(i) # append the list with current iterating index
print(type(l)) # <class'list'>
print(l)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lst = [i for i in range(0, 3)]
print(lst)
```

Comment: Please avoid using *builtin* ```list``` as variable name.

Answer (score 0):

Just print the list itself:

```
print(list(range(0, 3)))

# [0, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the `range` to list and print it.

```
elems = list(range(0,3))
print(elems)
```